# How to access neighbors for edges

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, networkx, breadth-first-search, path-finding

I'm trying to implement BFS in Python. I need to use weights between cities to calculate the shortest/best possible route. I couldn't understand how to add weights to a graph so decided to use Networkx for python. Please take a look at the following code

```
import networkx as nx

nodes = ["Arad","Zerind","Oradea","Timisoara","Lugoj","Mehadia"
        "Drobeta", "Sibiu","Rimnicu","Fagaras","Pitesti","Craiova"
        "Neamt","Bucharest","Giurgiu","Urziceni","Vaslui",
        "Iasi","Hirsova","Eforie"]

g ={
    ("Arad", "Sibiu", 140),("Arad", "Zerind", 75),("Arad", "Timisoara", 118),
    ("Zerind", "Oradea", 71),("Oradea", "Sibiu", 151),("Sibiu","Fagaras", 99),
    ("Sibiu", "Rimnicu", 90),("Timisoara","Lugoj", 111),("Lugoj", "Mehadia", 70),
    ("Mehadia","Drobeta",75),("Drobeta", "Craiova", 120), ("Sibiu","Fagaras", 99),
    ("Sibiu", "Rimnicu", 80),("Rimnicu","Pitesti",97),("Rimnicu","Craiova",146),
    ("Fagaras","Bucharest",211),("Pitesti","Bucharest",101),("Bucharest","Giurgiu",90),
    ("Bucharest","Urziceni",85),("Urziceni","Vaslui",142),("Vaslui","Iasi",92),
    ("Iasi","Neamt",87),("Urziceni","Hirsova",98),("Hirsova","Eforie",86)

}

graph = nx.Graph()
print ("Graph created")

for node in nodes:
  graph.add_node(node)

graph.add_weighted_edges_from(g)

for (n1,n2,dat) in graph.edges.data('weight'):
  neibors = graph[n1]
  print (neibors)
```

This is the output, I think it is fine

```
Graph created
{'Zerind': {'weight': 75}, 'Timisoara': {'weight': 118}, 'Sibiu': {'weight': 140}}
{'Zerind': {'weight': 75}, 'Timisoara': {'weight': 118}, 'Sibiu': {'weight': 140}}
{'Zerind': {'weight': 75}, 'Timisoara': {'weight': 118}, 'Sibiu': {'weight': 140}}
{'Arad': {'weight': 75}, 'Oradea': {'weight': 71}}
{'Sibiu': {'weight': 151}, 'Zerind': {'weight': 71}}
{'Lugoj': {'weight': 111}, 'Arad': {'weight': 118}}
{'Mehadia': {'weight': 70}, 'Timisoara': {'weight': 111}}
{'Rimnicu': {'weight': 90}, 'Oradea': {'weight': 151}, 'Fagaras': {'weight': 99}, 'Arad': {'weight': 140}}
{'Rimnicu': {'weight': 90}, 'Oradea': {'weight': 151}, 'Fagaras': {'weight': 99}, 'Arad': {'weight': 140}}
{'Craiova': {'weight': 146}, 'Sibiu': {'weight': 90}, 'Pitesti': {'weight': 97}}
{'Craiova': {'weight': 146}, 'Sibiu': {'weight': 90}, 'Pitesti': {'weight': 97}}
{'Bucharest': {'weight': 211}, 'Sibiu': {'weight': 99}}
{'Rimnicu': {'weight': 97}, 'Bucharest': {'weight': 101}}
{'Fagaras': {'weight': 211}, 'Pitesti': {'weight': 101}, 'Giurgiu': {'weight': 90}, 'Urziceni': {'weight': 85}}
{'Fagaras': {'weight': 211}, 'Pitesti': {'weight': 101}, 'Giurgiu': {'weight': 90}, 'Urziceni': {'weight': 85}}
{'Hirsova': {'weight': 98}, 'Vaslui': {'weight': 142}, 'Bucharest': {'weight': 85}}
{'Hirsova': {'weight': 98}, 'Vaslui': {'weight': 142}, 'Bucharest': {'weight': 85}}
{'Urziceni': {'weight': 142}, 'Iasi': {'weight': 92}}
{'Neamt': {'weight': 87}, 'Vaslui': {'weight': 92}}
{'Eforie': {'weight': 86}, 'Urziceni': {'weight': 98}}
{'Rimnicu': {'weight': 146}, 'Drobeta': {'weight': 120}}
{'Lugoj': {'weight': 70}, 'Drobeta': {'weight': 75}}
```

Now, I want to know how do I access the node and its connected nodes in a way that I can use to loop over to

1. read a node and check if it is explored
2. if not, get it's children and add them to queue
3. add them to explored set and expand them
4. Repeat the process until goal state is found

I'm new to python and so I need help accessing the data items from the graph.